# How do I ensure canvas is contained in viewport

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas that is the only thing on a page I want really want to see.  I'm trying to make it such that when I resize my window, I always have the entire canvas viewable with no scroll bars and maintain the aspect ratio.

### MCVE

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width;
let h = canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle = 'teal';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.rect(5, 5, w - 5, h - 5);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
* {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#canvasDiv {}

canvas#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="canvasDiv">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[All here at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pirr_/hj5kv8m9/16/)

With this attempt, it rescales just fine when I resize the width.  However, when I resize the height, I get overflow.

#### Resize Width with appropriate rescaling

[image]

#### Resize Height with unwanted overflow

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to read this article: [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width;
let h = canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle = 'teal';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.rect(5, 5, w - 5, h - 5);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
* {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


canvas#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  
}
```

```html
   <div id="canvasDiv">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"/>
    </div>
```